# After the callback function has been called, the focus or the selection should resume as it was before the callback started

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am looking for javascript or JQuery which help to resume the focus or selection after a callback function has been called. The controls in the page could be HTML controls or server controls.

A callback function is called regularly after every five seconds. This takes away the focus from the control or selection gets lost. Please provide me the codes for ASP.net.

I have been trying for three days but couldn’t get the solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event to remember the last element that had focus, and then call [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) on it once the callback has completed?

Comment: I am saying you should use the `blur` event to save the element that last had the focus. Have you tried this?

Comment: I cannot as there are several controls which are being cascaded throgh several nested master pages and code resides in one of the master page. It cannot have conttrol over the webform page. So the best solution is activeElement.

Answer (score -1):

Why not write your own script which will store the id of control having focus and keep it in Hidden field, reuse it after page load.

Happy Coding!!!